# Using matploblib plot crashes conda kernel

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda

I have conda 4.11.0 with Python 3.9.7 and dependencies

```
matplotlib-base==3.5.0
matplotlib==3.5.0
matplotlib-inline==0.1.2
numpy==1.21.2
numpy-base==1.21.2
```

(amongst other installed packages). When I try to create plots using matplotlib.pyplot:

```
plt.plot(...)
# OR-
plt.scatter(...)
```

It gives the error:

> OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libiomp5
> already initialized. OMP: Hint This means that multiple copies of the
> OpenMP runtime have been linked into the program. That is dangerous,
> since it can degrade performance or cause incorrect results. The best
> thing to do is to ensure that only a single OpenMP runtime is linked
> into the process, e.g. by avoiding static linking of the OpenMP
> runtime in any library. As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented
> workaround you can set the environment variable
> KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE to allow the program to continue to execute,
> but that may cause crashes or silently produce incorrect results. For
> more information, please see
> http://www.intel.com/software/products/support/.

Is the error cause due to "scikit-learn-intelex" package? Uninstalling "scikit-learn-intelex" package doesn't seem to fix the problem. It stills gives the message: "The kernel seems to have died. It will restart automatically".

What is causing this issue?